# Converting List of long values to comma separated along with paranthesis around the each value

Tags: java, spring-boot

For instance I have List and we need to convert it into comma separated vales along with paranthesis.

> For Ex : We have List values = {1234567, 6789034, 34534356}. We need to convert it into (1234567),(6789034),(34534356)

Comment: Replace the `, ` with `),(`, and the `{}` with `(` and `)`.

Comment: When you say list, do you mean an actual collection populated by those values, or do you just mean "we have this string representing a sequence of values"?

Comment: Either way, you need to show us your own attempt at solving this coding problem yourself, so that we can understand what you are really trying to do, and help you find a correct solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you consider a `List<String>` with the above values then its a case of simple string manipulation; where you just need to iterate over all the list elements, and store in a new list. The idea is this:

```
List<String> originalList = new ArrayList<String>();
originalList.add("1234567");
originalList.add("6789034");
originalList.add("34534356");

List<String> modifiedList = new ArrayList<String>();

int listSize = originalList.size();
for(int i=0; i< listSize; i++)
{
    String str = "";
    str+="("+originalList.get(i)+")";
    if(i < listSize - 1)
        str+=",";
    modifiedList.add(str);
}

modifiedList.forEach(System.out::println);
```